# Extract lines from a file using vim or teminal

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed, vim

I have the following in a file.  I'd like to use Vim or terminal to extract title and its content like this.

How can I achieve this?

```
Topic 1 - Core: Algebra
1.1
Arithmetic sequences and series; sum of finite arithmetic series; geometric sequences and series; sum of finite and infinite geometric series.
Sigma notation.
Applications.
1.2
Exponents and logarithms.
....
....
```

## file

```
"json_data" : {"data":[[{"data":{"title":"Topic 1 - Core: Algebra","attr":{"href":"javascript:void(0);"}},"attr":{"data-record-id":1885,"id":"syllabus_section_tree_node_1885"},"children":[{"data":{"title":"1.1","attr":{"href":"javascript:void(0);"}},"attr":{"data-record-id":1886,"id":"syllabus_section_tree_node_1886"},"children":[{"data":{"title":"Arithmetic sequences and series; sum of finite arithmetic series; geometric sequences and series; sum of finite and infinite geometric series.","attr":{"href":"javascript:void(0);"}},"attr":{"data-record-id":1895,"id":"syllabus_section_tree_node_1895"}},{"data":{"title":"Sigma notation.","attr":{"href":"javascript:void(0);"}},"attr":{"data-record-id":1896,"id":"syllabus_section_tree_node_1896"}},{"data":{"title":"Applications.","attr":{"href":"javascript:void(0);"}},"attr":{"data-record-id":1897,"id":"syllabus_section_tree_node_1897"}}]},{"data":{"title":"1.2","attr":{"href":"javascript:void(0);"}},"attr":{"data-record-id":1887,"id":"syllabus_section_tree_node_1887"},"children":[{"data":{"title":"Exponents and logarithms.","attr":{"href":"javascript:void(0);"}},"attr":{"data-record-id":1898,"id":"syllabus_section_tree_node_1898"}},{"data":{"title":"Laws of exponents; laws of logarithms.","attr":{"href":"javascript:void(0);"}},"attr":{"data-record-id":1899,"id":"syllabus_section_tree_node_1899"}},{"data":{"title":"Change of base.","attr":{"href":"javascript:void(0);"}},"attr":{"data-record-id":1900,"id":"syllabus_section_tree_node_1900"}}]},{"data":{"title":"1.3","attr":{"href":"javascript:void(0);"}},"attr":{"data-record-id":1888,"id":"syllabus_section_tree_node_1888"},
```

...
...

Comment: This is json. So you can use any JSON to object conversion (try php) and print the object in manner you like. You can see how to do this here -http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -oP '(?<="title":").*?(?=")' <INPUT_FILE>
```

### Explanation

- `grep -oP`: Use grep, printing only matches `-o` using Perl syntax `-p`.
- `(?<="title":")`: Perl lookbehind. Match a string that has `"title":"` before it.
- `.*?`: The actual part to match (and print). Match a "non-greedy" amount of characters before the lookahead (next).
- `(?="`): Perl lookahead. Match a string that has `"` after it.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), I'd use a JSON parser.

Python has a JSON library that's very simple to use — just make one function call and you get the data as a Python data structure which you can then iterate over.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import json, sys
def explore(tree):
    if isinstance(tree, list):
        for child in tree:
            explore(child)
        return
    if tree.has_key("title"):
        print tree["title"]
    if tree.has_key("data"):
        explore(tree["data"])
    if tree.has_key("children"):
        explore(tree["children"])
data = json.loads("{" + sys.stdin.read() + "}")["json_data"]
explore(data)
```